# how to show lof info of ffmpeg with nautilus scripts?

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg

Anybody knows how to take output log of ffmpeg, which may be like this

this command working well no log out put

> ffmpeg -sameq -ss [start_seconds] -t
>   [duration_seconds] -i [input_file]
>   [outputfile]

try to create log

> ffmpeg -sameq -ss [start_seconds] -t
>   [duration_seconds] -i [input_file]
>   [outputfile]   **$1 >> TEST.log**

well its not working :(

i m using Ubuntu release 8.04 (hardy) gnome 2.22.3

Comment: how to show lof info of ffmpeg with nautilus scripts ?

its not lof  (title)  > 

how to show log info of ffmpeg with nautilus scripts ?

Answer (score 1):

`fmpeg -sameq -ss [start_seconds] -t [duration_seconds] -i [input_file] [outputfile] 2>> TEST.log`

the 2 insures that you redirect stderr instead of stdout, all the ffmpeg output goes to stderr.

The one problem I saw figuring this out, is that ffmpeg does not check if its input is open, or whether its output is redirected, so it will stall with a "overwrite [y/n]?" prompt if the output file already exists.

Comment: log is coming but outputfile is 0 bytes :( not working

Comment: The $1 should not have been in there, but that following command creates a log file on my computer. "ffmpeg -sameq -ss 5 -t 20 -i test.mp4 test2.mp4 2>> TEST.log"

Comment: fmpeg -sameq -ss [start_seconds] -t [duration_seconds] -i [input_file] [outputfile] 2>> TEST.log <<....... this one is working thanks